# Arduino Code for simple DC Motor to control the position and allow fix periodic motion of arm between two switches connected on left and right side

Tags: c++, arduino

Circuit For Incubator.
DC Motor

Hello Every one i am working on incubator to make it fully automatic. i used the code attached to change position of the plates every 3 hours, since it is a simple DC motor, and has no accurate position control. thus activating motor for 2 second in forward and then for 2 second in reverse does not bring the motor arm back to its actual position(Movement in forward is more than in reverse for same 2 seconds activation). So this method is not the best choice.

Now i want to use two switches on left and right position, the motor hand should oscillate in between the switches.
At start the arduino should move the motor hand to one of the side(Left or Right) by checking the status of the Switches, IF hand reaches the left switch, it should delay there for 3 hours and after that move the hand to right untill right switch is pressed, and stop there and wait for 3 Hours again, and then move again to left.

I need this cycle to continue again and again.

Please help me in this code.
Thanks all in advance

```
    int pin7 = 7;
int pin6 = 6;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pin6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pin7, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pin6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(pin7, LOW);
}
void loop(){
  digitalWrite(pin6, HIGH);
  delay(2000);
  digitalWrite(pin6, LOW);
  delay(10800000);   //Delay 3 Hours
  digitalWrite(pin7, HIGH);
  delay(2500);
  digitalWrite(pin7, LOW);
  delay(10800000);   //Delay 3 hours
}
```

Comment: what is your question? reading switches is covered by a million tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

## full code

```
// define motorPotiton class to tell you  wher the moter
enum class MotorPosition
{
  one,
  two,
  unknown_positon
};

// define connections location passed on your hardware
const int switch_one_pin = 4;
const int switch_two_pin = 5;
const int motor_forward_Pin = 7;
const int motor_backward_pin = 6;

void setup()
{
  // define direction of connection
  pinMode(motor_backward_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor_forward_Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(switch_one_pin, INPUT);
  pinMode(switch_two_pin, INPUT);

  // set motor in second location at start
  changeMotorPosition(MotorPosition::two);
}
void loop()
{
  changeMotorPosition(MotorPosition::one);
  delay(10800000); //Delay 3 Hours
  changeMotorPosition(MotorPosition::two);
  delay(10800000); //Delay 3 hours
}


//******************************************************************
//           ****       helper functions       ****
// ******************************************************************

void changeMotorPosition(MotorPosition newPosition)
{
  // define a static variable to save cuerrnet location 
  // if you don't know what is static means .. you could think of it as a global variable but just inside this function ...means only ceareated one time
  static MotorPosition motorCurrentPosition = MotorPosition::unknown_positon;

  // if motor is alerady in the correct place then do nothing
  if(getActualPosition() == newPosition ){
          // just make sure that you update the current poition
           motorCurrentPosition = newPosition;
          return;
  }

  if(getActualPosition() == MotorPosition::unknown_positon){
    // motor is not in one of it's the position
    // this will happen if motor dose note have selfLock system 
    // so we will check on last saved position
    if(motorCurrentPosition == newPosition){
      // if you like you could rest the motor to correct place 
      // but i will let it not so important 
      // TO DO : make motor go back to correct place 
      return;
    }
  }

  // now let see were you like to go
  switch (newPosition)
  {
  case MotorPosition::one:
        // go forward untill you reach the second position
        while (digitalRead(switch_two_pin) == LOW)
        {
          digitalWrite(motor_forward_Pin,HIGH); 
        }
        // then stop motor
        digitalWrite(motor_forward_Pin,LOW);
        //change the currnt location Programmaticlly
        motorCurrentPosition = MotorPosition::one;
        
    break;

  case MotorPosition::two:
        // go backword untill you reach the first position
        while (digitalRead(switch_one_pin) == LOW)
        {
          digitalWrite(motor_backward_pin,HIGH); 
        }
        // then stop motor
        digitalWrite(motor_forward_Pin,LOW);
        //change the currnt location programmaticlly
        motorCurrentPosition = MotorPosition::two;
    break;

  default:
        // that means newPosition == unknown position
        // do nothing this will be error in calling function
    break;
  }
}

// the follloiwing function will return the acuall location of motor
MotorPosition getActualPosition(){
  if(digitalRead(switch_one_pin) == HIGH) return MotorPosition::one;
  if(digitalRead(switch_two_pin)==HIGH) return MotorPosition::two;
  return MotorPosition::unknown_positon;
}
```

### some explaination

first you need to know that arduino code is just a `c++` code so if you already know `c++` then you found it easy to understand

```
enum class MotorPosition
{
  one,
  two,
  unknown_positon
};
```

as you see i creat `enum class` with name of `MotorPosition` to use it as a position variable this will give you the ability to make the variable of type `MotorPosition` and it only accept one of three value (one,two,unkonwn)

```
// look at int type can take any number value 
int a = 5;
// look at MotorPositon type can take one of it's value like this
MotorPosition b = MotorPosition::one;
```

[read more on enum class in cpp](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enum-classes-in-c-and-their-advantage-over-enum-datatype/)

then i mead `changeMotorPosition` function which will help you to change the motor location just give it the position location and it will go for it you can call it like that

```
changeMotorPosition(MotorPosition::one); // go for first location
changeMotorPosition(MotorPosition::two); // go for second location
```

now read the all code and have fun with it :)

Comment: Thanks for detailed Answer Sir Ibram Reda, I am just trying the code in my Project.
May God Bless you and your family. 
Thanks once again for Support.